# Trying to install hadoop Bigtop on VM running on windows 8

Tags: linux, hadoop, terminal

I am trying to learn about hadoop and its tool ,I am following book  *Hadoop for dummies* (which is appropriate)  It gives me a bunch of steps ,they are 
after I set up  CentOS 6  on Virtual Machine

1>Open terminal /// Done

2>Go to root with the profile provided //Done

3Download bigTop repository with this command :

```
wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/bigtop.repo \]
      http://www.apache.org/dist/bigtop/bigtop-0.7.0/repos/centos6/bigtop.repo]
```

//Done

4  Install the tools in hadoop using this commmand:

```
yum install hadoop\* mahout\* oozie\* hbase\* hive\* hue\* pig\* zookeeper\*
```

//Done

5  Download and install Java:`yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64`
//Done

6  Format the NameNode:`sudo /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode init`
// here it gives me error as `sudo :/etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode init command not found`

I am new to linux enviroment and commands , and really don't understand what I need to do here.

Thanks in advance for our help.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Run following command again :

```
yum install hadoop\*
```

and then try step 6.